# Angular JS - How can I hide button when all items from array is invisible

Tags: angularjs, button, visible

I am having one button - ON tapping on button, we are showing drop-down list
 On tapping of list item, I am making item's visibility false
 I want to hide button when all items are invisible
 And show button if we have a single item visible from list

I have tried this - [Please suggest some simplified code if you are having]

I am calling some function on click in which I am doing this - I am running a loop of list items from which I am taking number of invisible items ... And once my invisible item's length is similar to my actual list length, I am hiding the button .. So once I get a single item visible, my button will get shown

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to a select?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: How you showing item?

Comment: I have tried this : I am calling some function on click in which I am doing this - I am running a loop of list items from which I am taking number of invisible items ... And once my invisible item's length is similar to my actual list length, I am hiding the button .. So once I get a single item visible, my button will get shown

Comment: @Curious_k.shree so, you have a working solution. What's the problem then?

Comment: I want to use filters to make it simplified if any other way is there

Comment: A filter is not really an appropriate solution for this problem, IMO. But you could use `ng-show="hasVisibleItem()"`, and define this function in the scope as `return items.some(function(item) { return item.visible; });`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it successfully with the help of .$filter

```
var filterLength = $filter('filter')(gloabalFilterOptions, { isVisible: true }).length;
        if (filterLength > 0) {
            $scope.showFilterLabel = true;
        } else {
            $scope.showFilterLabel = false;
        }
```